# C - fscanf error with char *

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure, scanf

I'm trying to read a txt file with this format:

```
8590 2 07 Goku
8591 2 07 Vegeta
6973 2 07 Picolo
5432 3 02 Jerez
6773 3 02 Sour
4689 4 03 Mosco
6981 5 06 Cabba
7891 5 06 Frost
```

The columns are: hp, universe color, universe number and name. What I do is this read the line and save the parameters in an array of structures called warrior with this format:

```
typedef struct Warrior{
    int hp;
    int color;
    int universe;
    char * name;
    int posX;
    int posY;
    int ki;
} warrior;

warrior createWarrior(int inHp, int inColor, int inUniverse, char * inName){
    warrior guerrero; 
    guerrero.hp = inHp;
    guerrero.color = inColor;
    guerrero.universe = inUniverse;
    guerrero.name = inName;
    guerrero.posX= 0;
    guerrero.posY= 0;
    guerrero.ki=0;
    return guerrero;
}
```

The readFile code is:

```
warrior * readFile(char * nameFile, warrior * listGuerrero){
    FILE * filePointer;
    int sizeFile = 0, ch = 0;
    int inHp, inColor, inUniverse;
    char inName[50];

    filePointer = fopen(nameFile, "r");

    while(fscanf(filePointer, "%d %d %d %s\n", &inHp, &inColor, &inUniverse, inName) != EOF){
        sizeFile ++;
    }

    rewind(filePointer);

    listGuerrero = (warrior *)malloc(sizeFile*sizeof(warrior));
    for(int k = 0; k < sizeFile; k++){
        fscanf(filePointer, "%d %d %d %s\n", &inHp, &inColor, &inUniverse, &inName[0]);
        listGuerrero[k] = createWarrior(inHp,inColor,inUniverse,inName);
        printf("k: %d - HP: %d - Color: %d - Universo: %d - Nombre: %s \n", k, listGuerrero[k].hp, listGuerrero[k].color, listGuerrero[k].universe, listGuerrero[k].name);
    }

    fclose(filePointer);
    return listGuerrero;
}
```

But for some reason I can't understand, the final list of warriors all have the same name like:

```
j: 0 - HP: 8590 - Color: 2 - Universo: 7 - Nombre: Frost 
j: 1 - HP: 8591 - Color: 2 - Universo: 7 - Nombre: Frost 
j: 2 - HP: 6973 - Color: 2 - Universo: 7 - Nombre: Frost 
j: 3 - HP: 5432 - Color: 3 - Universo: 2 - Nombre: Frost 
j: 4 - HP: 6773 - Color: 3 - Universo: 2 - Nombre: Frost 
j: 5 - HP: 4689 - Color: 4 - Universo: 3 - Nombre: Frost 
j: 6 - HP: 6981 - Color: 5 - Universo: 6 - Nombre: Frost 
j: 7 - HP: 7891 - Color: 5 - Universo: 6 - Nombre: Frost
```

Is something wrong with the inName pointer?

When I debug, the first iteration prints:

```
j: 0 - HP: 8590 - Color: 2 - Universo: 7 - Nombre: Goku
```

And the second iteration prints:

```
j: 0 - HP: 8590 - Color: 2 - Universo: 7 - Nombre: Vegeta 
j: 1 - HP: 8591 - Color: 2 - Universo: 7 - Nombre: Vegeta
```

and so on.

Comment: Note that it's the last name to be read that is preserved. Because you didn't save the names separately; you just copy the pointer to `inName` into the structure, rather than allocating space and making a copy of the name.  Since `inName` is a local variable to the read function, you'll also find that the names get corrupted, sooner rather than later.  You should show the structure definition too, though it is clear that you have a `char *` for the name in the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you read the first name and after that for every warrior in the file you just set a pointer to that first name. For every element from your file you must allocate new memory for it's name (using malloc) and copy the new name into it( using strcpy). Because you declared the name char*

```
warrior createWarrior(int inHp, int inColor, int inUniverse, char * inName){

    warrior guerrero; 
    guerrero.hp = inHp;
    guerrero.color = inColor;
    guerrero.universe = inUniverse;

    guerrero.name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 30); // 30 is the length of the name

    strcpy(guerrero.name,inName); // copy new name 
    guerrero.posX= 0;
    guerrero.posY= 0;
    guerrero.ki=0;

    return guerrero;

}
```

There is another cool way to do it using strdup() which basically alocates new memory and copy the parameter string there ( but i've not tested this):

```
warrior createWarrior(int inHp, int inColor, int inUniverse, char * inName){

    warrior guerrero; 
    guerrero.hp = inHp;
    guerrero.color = inColor;
    guerrero.universe = inUniverse;

    guerrero.name = strdup(inName);
    guerrero.posX= 0;
    guerrero.posY= 0;
    guerrero.ki=0;

    return guerrero;

}
```

Don't forget:

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your input from scanf is written to the same memory location given for inName[50]. In each iterration you are overwritting the content, but assigning the same address to the guerrero.name. And when you print out, you get last entry printed.

You may try this:

```
warrior createWarrior(int inHp, int inColor, int inUniverse, char * inName){
...
guerrero.name = strdup(inName);
....
return guerrero;
}
```